# Firebase Authentication using Facebook 'App not active' error

Tags: firebase, facebook, firebase-authentication

Im trying to use Facebook to sign in to my web app. I works for me but not when my friend tried it. This pop up instead of Facebook sign in that i got.
[App not active error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VawB.png)

I have checked for both the App id and secret, they both matched and the redirect URI matched too.
[firebase facebook provider settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c729I.png)

[facebook dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxGGs.png)
[facebook dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Znui.png)

What might caused the error?

Edit 1:

The app is in **development** mode. [App mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3FnO.jpg).

Im not sure about submission for permission and features for review since it is not in the Firebase documentation for Facebook authentication but here is a screenshot on the permission and features tab on Facebook dashboard [Facebook Dashboard permission and features tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAnHK.jpg).

Comment: What app mode is your app currently in? (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-modes) Have you submitted all the permissions and features that require it, for review yet?

Comment: hi @CBroe. The app is in development mode and im not sure about the permission and features submission. I have explained on edit 1.